# Prevent background-image from scaling when user zooms in or out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have this transparent raster-like background-overlay: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ26H.png) <-- try zooming out your browser to see the effect

When zooming in or out (especially on mobile devices this happens a lot) the image tends to look smudgy and ugly. Is there a way to have this background-image always be 10 x 10 pixels in size on the screen no matter how the page is zoomed, so it always looks sharp?

Doing some searches I found that this might be a hard task. In case it is impossible: is there a way to alter the zooming filters in a way the image looks better when zoomed out or in?

Answer (score 1):

On Hi-Res display, like mobile devices' display, you will always have the blurry effect because of the high pixels density due to the high resolution on a small size screen.

There is a workaround to fix this:

- Create a double sized background image: your image is 10px 10px, create a 20px 20px one instead.
- Apply the background image using the desired size: `background-size: 10px 10px;`

With this trick, when zooming in or viewing the image on Hi-Res display the image will not appears blurry anymore.

As requested in comments, here is the code to adapt the background size to the zoom:

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
if (window.addEventListener){           
    window.addEventListener('resize', setBackground, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', setBackground);
}

function setBackground(){
    document.body.style.backgroundSize =
        (((( window.screen.width / ( window.screen.width / getImageWidth() )) / 10) > 1 ) ? (( window.screen.width / ( window.screen.width / getImageWidth() )) / 10) : 1) + "%";
}

function getImageWidth(){

    var imageSrc = document
                    .body
                     .style
                      .backgroundImage
                       .replace(/url\((['"])(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2')
                        .split(',')[0];

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;

    var width = image.width;

    return width;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onLoad="javascript:setBackground();" style="background: url(bkg.jpg) repeat;">
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! The biggest problem though is zooming out. Zooming in makes it blurry, but that's acceptable. Zooming out makes it ugly (also due to the kind of background image I use). But what I'm really trying to find out if it's possible that the background image always uses the proper amount of pixels on the screen (so that an image with imagesize 10 x 10 px always uses 10 x 10 px on the screen), no matter what zoom level.

Comment: I've made some tries... Your idea it's basically to set a bigger image if the user zoom out and a littler one if zoom in. That's right?

Comment: Edited the post. The formula is not perfect, need some changes. But that's the way for your idea.

Comment: Formula changed. Now works well with small and big backgrounds. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, @Cirou! Can't quite figure it out yet though. I've tried your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/TPVSZ/. On different zoom levels it still shows the 'uglyness' I was talking about. Also, when I resize the browser, your code seems to set the background-size to 0%, thus showing no background.

I've added this image to clarify what I mean (be sure to view it at full size: [Click here to view image!](http://kasperkoman.com/backgroundzooming.png)

Please fiddle around as you wish ;)!

Comment: I've made some changes: an IE compatibility fix and a check to see if percent value is less than 1%. But your background still looks weird on some zoom conditions... i think it's a browser rendering problem. I'll try to find a solution.